# Azure Storage Blob Python modulewill NOT be recognized when running on azure batch node

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

I’m trying to run a python script on Azure Batch nodes. One of the required things I need in this file is

```
import azure.storage.blob
```

Of which I need to use the BlobServiceClient class from that module. When I try to access the BSC class, it tells me that no attribute of the name BSC (for short) exists in the azure.storage.blob module. Here are the things I have done

1. I’ve ran the script on my local machine. The script works perfectly
2. Python3 —version returns 3.8.10 on my AZ nodes
3. I have downloaded the azure-storage-blob module on my Azure computer nodes (which are Linux nodes)

What might I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have not [prepared your compute node](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/jobs-and-tasks#start-task) with the proper software or the task execution environment does not have the proper context. Please read the documentation about [Azure Batch jobs and tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/jobs-and-tasks).